# How to mark a property as non serializable for json?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

As the title says, I want to mark a property as non serializable by the JavascriptSerializer. How can achive that ? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I *think* you just want to apply the [`ScriptIgnoreAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.scriptignoreattribute.aspx):

```
[ScriptIgnore]
public string IgnoreThis { get; set; }
```

Comment: Thank you Jon, this is what I was looing for. Happy coding.

Answer (score 14):

If you are needing this for `ASP.NET Core` or even before that, you should be using:

```
[JsonIgnore]
```

you'll need to reference:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
```

Answer (score 0):

As of .NET 3.0, you can use [DataContract](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractattribute?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-3.0) instead of Serializable. With the DataContract though, you will need to either "opt-in" by marking the serializable fields with the [DataMember](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.serialization.datamemberattribute?view=netframework-3.0) attribute; or "opt-out" using the [IgnoreDataMember](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.serialization.ignoredatamemberattribute?view=netframework-3.0).

The main difference between opt-in vs opt-out is that opt-out by default will only serialize public members, while opt-in will only serialize the marked members (regardless of protection level).

Note that if you are using Newtonsoft.Json for your serialization (like in my case), it [supports](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/ReducingSerializedJSONSize.htm#JsonIgnoreAttributeAndDataMemberAttribute) DataContract as well.